# It possible to add to wix site Google AdMob app-add.text file?

Tags: app-store, velo

I need to upload the new AdMob demand for iOS app,
is its possible to upload tex file to free wix site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with GitHub pages and upload the app-add.text.

https://pages.github.com